# Javascript Promise what im doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the javascript `Promise` but still the catch still execute first before the `ajax` what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-group-agent-upload", function () {

    var file = $("#group-agent-file").val();
    var file = $("#group-agent-file").prop("files")[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');

    reader.onload = Insert_Bulk_Agent;



});
```

and this is the function

```
function Insert_Bulk_Agent(event) {

var result = event.target.result;
var data = $.csv.toObjects(result);
var length = data.length;
var count = 0;
var arrayCollection = [];

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (length > 0) {

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

        if(val.AgentStatus == "" || val.BirthDate == "" || val.CSP == "" || val.Classification == "" || val.ContactNumber == "" ||
            val.EmailAddress == "" || val.FirstName == "" || val.LastName == "" || val.MiddleName == "" || val.LiveDate == "") {
            $.ajax({
                success: function () {
                    //console.log('ok');
                    //var tbody = $("#error-list").find("tbody");
                    //$(tbody).append("<tr><td>" + val.MiddleName + "</td><td>" + val.LastName + "</tr>");
                    arrayCollection.push(val);
                    console.log('test');
                }
            });
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        var percentageCompleted = count / length * 100;
                        updateUploadPercentage(parseInt(percentageCompleted));

                    };
                    return xhr;
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/Insert_Bulk_Agent",
                data: JSON.stringify(val),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {


                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert("error in Insert_Bulk_AgentInfo()");
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                }

            });

        }

    });
    }
    else {

        alert("The selected file is empty");

    }
    resolve();
}).catch(() => {
    console.log(arrayCollection[0]);
})


}
```

the `arrayCollection[0]` returns undefined

Comment: the catch executes? that suggests you reject, but I see no reject - but basically, there is no need to use Promise's in that code, as the Promise isn't returned anyway. And, finally, you call `resolve` without waiting for any asynchronous code to complete

Comment: How can I do this right because I read the article `https://blog.timsommer.be/using-promises-to-merge-async-jquery-ajax-calls/` and the example does not make sense for me. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: why are you instantiating a new Promise? you don't need it.

Comment: Because I need to access the value of the `arrayCollection` in the `ajax success`

Comment: If you catch something, you might as well have an error in your code. How about you log the error and see for yourself? `.catch((err) => console.error(err))`

Comment: there is no error encoutnered.

Comment: `Because I need to access the value ...` you can do that without using a promise - the promise is redundant. If you need `arrayCollection` to be 1:1 mapped with `data` array (is it an array?) then you'll need to use Promise.all and array.map

Comment: also ...`return $.ajax({
                        success: function () {
                            arrayCollection.push(val);
                            console.log('test');
                        }
                    });` - this is 3 types of crazy

Comment: Yeah but when I am trying to access the `arrayCollection` outside the `$.each` it returns `undefined` because the `ajax` is not yeat completed.

Comment: yes, so Promises do not make asynchronous code synchronouos - is the order of data in `arrayCollection` important?

Comment: the error is possibly due to `$.ajax({success: function () { ... }})` ... what does $.ajax do when it's only parameter is a success function? - oh, I see, it loads the current page using AJAX - why would you do that?

Comment: seems like you want something like https://jsfiddle.net/etujmrtu/

Comment: @JaromandaX Use answer if you have solution

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Can you post your html

Comment: @bigless, I know how stack overflow works, however, I'm not going to post an answer, seeing as the code doesn't make sense (why is it loading the current page using AJAX, then doing nothing with the result???? and why is **that** the important thing to save in an array, whereas the upload ajax is not important?)

Comment: in fact, https://jsfiddle.net/etujmrtu/1/ is identical in functionality, without the extra superfluous $.ajax calls to wait for - or even https://jsfiddle.net/etujmrtu/2/

Comment: the first `ajax` is to create a csv file that meet the first condition. and the second `ajax` is to upload the data that have no null values.